# How to tell atom editor to open .bashrc with shell script highlighting?

Tags: atom-editor

Every time I open my `.bashrc` file with atom it assumes it is plain text and I need to tell it the file is actually a shell scripts to format and highlight it properly. Is there way to permanently tell atom always assume `.bashrc` file is a shell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following to your Atom configuration (`config.cson`):

```
"*":
  core:
    customFileTypes:
      "source.shell": [
        "*.bashrc"
      ]
```

Make sure not to overwrite your existing configuration and nest the `customFileTypes` key correctly, since [CSON](https://github.com/bevry/cson) is an indentation-sensitive format.